# Microsoft Cognitive Web Search has different results/structure

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using AZ Cognitive to monitor LinkedIn data for a research project. If I do the same query on both `bing.com` and using the Cognitive API, I get different information in the snippet portion of the results. From regular Bing search I can see a profiles occupation. From within the API it displays a generic LinkedIn message.

I have attached a screenshot of the regular Bing search results and raw JSON from the Cognitive API.

```
{u'name': u'Daniel Barclay at Rackspace, the #1 managed cloud company ...', u'url': u'REMOVED LINK', u'dateLastCrawled': u'2017-07-07T18:49:00', u'displayUrl': u'REMOVED LINK', u'snippet': u"View Daniel Barclay\u2019s professional profile on LinkedIn. LinkedIn is the world's largest business network, helping professionals like Daniel Barclay discover inside ...", u'id': u'REMOVED LINK'}
```

```
{u'about': [{u'name': u'Bill Ramsey'}], u'name': u'Bill Ramsey at Rackspace | LinkedIn', u'url': u'REMOVED LINK', u'dateLastCrawled': u'2017-07-07T01:00:00', u'displayUrl': u'REMOVED LINK', u'snippet': u"View Bill Ramsey\u2019s professional profile on LinkedIn. LinkedIn is the world's largest business network, helping professionals like Bill Ramsey discover inside ...", u'id': u'REMOVED LINK'}
```

[image: Cognitive Search]

*** EDIT ***
If you use the search string below as a baseline you will see the difference between the two searches:

SEARCH STRING - site:linkedin.com/in/ "at rackspace"

1. Search bing.com with that string.
2. Search that string using the api.

The api endpoint I am using is: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search

Answer (score 0):

Share the parameters and URL used to call cognitive API.

Comment: edited original post to include search string and api endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sandbox to check the output JSON. I have tried with a trial key and it results are same for both Bing.com and at sandbox. can u please check it here your result.
https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d/console